# Unexpected sql statement in belongsTo Laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel

My `belongsTo` relationship has a following structure:

```
public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'author_id', 'id');
}
```

And it produces the following query (when executing `$message->author()->getResults()->toSql()`):

`select * from "users" where "users"."id" is null and "users"."deleted_at" is null limit 1`

`$message` does contain a valid `Message` instance, its `author_id` is set and a relevant `User` exists.

Edit 1: As pointed out by @Jonas Staudenmeir my original code wasn't what I actually had in my code. The comments below hold, though, as I simply mismatched the params when typing out the question. I've edited the code to be an accurate representation of what's in the project.

Edit 2: Included the Message model. The "attachments()" relation works fine, by the way.

```
class Message extends Model
{
    use \Eloquent\Dialect\Json;
    use \Spatie\Macroable\Macroable;
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [
        'id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at',
    ];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $jsonColumns = [];

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'author_id', 'id');
    }

    public function attachments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\File', 'file_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you `dd($message->author);`

Comment: it can be so that `$message` has an author which has no entry in the author table so it is showing null and you are facing a problem this can be solved with an optional keyword like `$message->optional(author())->getResult()`

Comment: @LukeSnowden the following query: `select * from "users" where "users"."id" is null and "users"."deleted_at" is null`

@indrashastri If I understood you right, you're implying that there is no valid user (author) for the message? If so, that's untrue and I stated that in the question. If you meant something else, could you elaborate?

Comment: What's the result of `dd($message->author()->toSql());`? As @LukeSnowden asked: What's the result of `dd($message->author);`? It can't be an SQL query.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir `dd($message->author)` is `null`, while `toSql()` is the original query I mentioned (with the `users.id = null`).
I apologize again for the initial mixup.

Comment: Run `dd($message->author_id);`.

Comment: `int 1`. There is an entry in users where `id = 1`

Comment: Please post the whole `Message` model.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Added it. Or did you need the `dd($message)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169609/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-ivan-talanov).

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the parameter order:

```
public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'author_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that's the way it actually was in the code. The code originally mentioned in the question resulted in a fatal error about `users.author_id` not existing. Thanks for the answer though, it did make me double-check the code & the question. I've edited it to reflect that.